# Apple developer account for multiply computers

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to use Apple Developer Account on multiply MacBooks (e.g. 2)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Go into the Xcode organizer, click Developer Profile on the left and click export at the bottom. Then import into your other mac via the same method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to export the certificate you created on the first machine and add it to the keychain on the second machine. Now just grab all the profiles and you are done.

Repeat for any other machines you would like to develop on.

Comment: note that you can't export the private and the public key at once. if keychain want's to create a `.cer`file it will not work. you have to export the private key seperatly .. it will be saved in a `.p12` file.

Comment: I've always used p12 fot to export both the private and public at once. Never had any problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a company apple dev account, you can setup multiple developers without paying extra for each developer.

You just need to export the development certificate you initially created, and add it to the new mac before you start developing.